# After Simulate('change') state is not updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, redux-mock-store

I've got a search filter component with an input inside it, and it's connected to redux.

```
class SearchFilter extends PureComponent {
   constructor (props) {
       super(props);
       this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
       this.state = {
           keyword: props.searchKeyword
       };
   }

   handleInputChange (e) {
       this.setState({keyword: e.target.value});
       this.props.dispatch(SetFiltersValue(...);
   }

   render () {
       const {keyword} = this.state;
       return (
           <div className="search-w bp3-input-group">
               <span className="bp3-icon bp3-icon-search"/>
               <input className="bp3-input" value={keyword} type="text" placeholder="Search input" dir="auto" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
           </div>
       );
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = (_, ownParams) => {...};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchFilter);
```

I wrote a test in jest and enzyme to test state updates when user enters a new value

```
import React from "react";
import SearchFilter from "../../dev/components/shared/searchFilter";
import {shallow, mount} from "enzyme";
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";

describe("Testing Search filter", () => {
    const mockStore = configureStore(),
        initialStoreState = {
            filtersParams: {}
        };
    let store;

    beforeEach(() => {
        store = mockStore(initialStoreState);
    });

    it("Update search field value when user enters a value", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<SearchFilter store={store}/>).dive(),
            searchInput = wrapper.find("input.bp3-input").first();

        expect(searchInput).toBeDefined();

        const mockedEvent = {
            preventDefault () {},
            target: { value: "foo" }
        };
        expect(wrapper.state("keyword")).toEqual("");
        searchInput.simulate("change", mockedEvent);
        wrapper.update();
        expect(wrapper.state("keyword")).toEqual("foo");
    });
});
```

The problem is that state does't update after simulating change, and test always fails.

How can I fix this or is there other way to test state updates?

Comment: it("responds to name change", done => {
  const handleChangeSpy = sinon.spy(New.prototype, "handleChange");
  const event = {target: {name: "pollName", value: "spam"}};
  const wrap = mount(
    <New />
  );
  wrap.ref('pollName').simulate('change', event);
  expect(handleChangeSpy.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
})

Comment: @DhavalPatel that test case will just test if event handler was called, I want to test if state updated.

Comment: why don't you try the .setState()  methods of enzyme. as you have mock your onChange event so while simulate change event it will not check anything about the state.

Answer (score 0):

A completed testing example:

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { connect, DispatchProp } from 'react-redux';
import { SetFiltersValue } from './actionCreators';

interface ISearchFilterStateProps {
  searchKeyword: string;
}

interface ISearchFilterState {
  keyword: string;
}

type Props = ISearchFilterStateProps & DispatchProp;

class SearchFilter extends PureComponent<Props, ISearchFilterState> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      keyword: props.searchKeyword
    };
  }

  public handleInputChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    this.setState({ keyword: e.target.value });
    this.props.dispatch(SetFiltersValue());
  }

  public render() {
    const { keyword } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="search-w bp3-input-group">
        <span className="bp3-icon bp3-icon-search" />
        <input
          className="bp3-input"
          value={keyword}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search input"
          dir="auto"
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (_, ownParams) => {
  return { searchKeyword: '' };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchFilter);
```

`actionCreators.ts`:

```
export const SetFiltersValue = () => ({ type: 'SET_FILTER' });
```

Unit test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import SearchFilter from './';
import { SetFiltersValue } from './actionCreators';

const initialState = { filtersParams: {} };
type State = typeof initialState;
const mockStore = configureStore<State>();

describe('SearchFilter', () => {
  let store;
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(initialState);
  });
  it('t1', () => {
    const searchFilter = shallow(<SearchFilter store={store}></SearchFilter>).dive();
    const searchInputWrapper = searchFilter.dive();
    const searchInput = searchInputWrapper.find('input.bp3-input').first();
    expect(searchInputWrapper.state('keyword')).toBe('');

    const mockedEvent = {
      preventDefault: jest.fn(),
      target: { value: 'foo' }
    };
    searchInput.simulate('change', mockedEvent);
    expect(searchInputWrapper.state('keyword')).toBe('foo');
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([SetFiltersValue()]);
    expect(searchInputWrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```bash
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/54587960/index.spec.tsx
  SearchFilter
    ✓ t1 (28ms)

 › 1 snapshot written.
-------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File               |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files          |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 actionCreators.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx         |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Snapshot Summary
 › 1 snapshot written from 1 test suite.

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 written, 1 total
Time:        4.367s, estimated 5s
```

React Component Snapshot:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`SearchFilter t1 1`] = `"<div class=\\"search-w bp3-input-group\\"><span class=\\"bp3-icon bp3-icon-search\\"></span><input type=\\"text\\" class=\\"bp3-input\\" value=\\"foo\\" placeholder=\\"Search input\\" dir=\\"auto\\"/></div>"`;
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/54587960